# Please tell me how to send emails with single or multiple attachments.I know how to send email without attachments

Tags: php

I know how to send email without attachments.
Please tell me how to send emails with single or multiple attachments.
php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
$from=$_SESSION['email'];
to=$_POST['to'];
date1=strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"));
subject=$_POST['subject'];
message=$_POST['message'];
$success=mail($to, "$subject", $message, "From:" . $from);
if($success) { //Email response
$mailsendquery="INSERT INTO mails (to_mail,from_mail,subject,body,date) VALUES('$to','$from','$subject','$message',$date1)";
$mailsendres=mysqli_query($db,$mailsendquery);
?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Successfully sent!</h4>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Invalid Mail Address!</h4>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: you have to provide us your current code.... otherwise we cant help you

Comment: You attach and then send it. You're welcome.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)

Answer (score 2):

For your sake, I would recommend using PHPMailer (industry standard). Using mail() isn't a one-two-go! PHPMailer has easy attachment integration, and is quickly set up (as in a few lines of code).

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer